# How to overload an operator with multiple parameters like a + b + c?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I can operate class+class (for example I can do date+date), but can anyone explain how can I do class+class+class please? C++ does not let me define an operator with 2 parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  It would be worth documenting which similar threads you found.  However, C++ does not allow you to create 3-argument operators, so you will have to create regular functions and use them as regular functions to achieve the required effect: `date average_date(date d1, date d2, date d3)` or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I cannot use another function. I need to define class+class+class somehow because my input is like that.

Answer (score 9):

That's because there is no such operator in general.
`a + b + c` is `(a + b) + c`.  First `a + b`, then the results
of that added to `c`.

EDIT:

If the objects in question are extremely big, so that creating
the temporaries in an expression like `a + b + c` is too
expensive, you can google for template expressions; the basic
idea is that `operator+` doesn't do anything but return an
expression node, which can be evaluated later, as part of the
full expression.

Answer (score 1):

By making them friends of the class, you would make sure they are binary operators, and define them separately, like so:

```
class someclass
{
     int a;
public:
     someclass();
     ...
     friend someclass operator+(const someclass & lhs, const someclass & rhs);
};

someclass operator+(const someclass &lhs, const someclass &rhs)
{
     someclass a = lhs;
     a.a = a.a + rhs.a;
     return a;
}
```

you will, of course need to define a copy constructor (someclass(const someclass & old);) and the other functions of the class, but this method has always worked for me, and it was how I was taught in college.

Comment: Which doesn't answer his question.  (And the usual way of getting `operator+` is to define `operator+=` in the class, and inherit from a class template which provides `operator+` as a function of `operator+=`.

Comment: And both of the arguments ot `operator+` should be `const`, not just the `rhs`.

Comment: @JamesKanze I have never heard of doing it that way, so I am not able to include that in my suggestion, though it seems like a viable way to do it. The easiest way to solve the OP's problem is to use a binary operator, which is what I was getting at. And I fixed the const problem for lhs

Comment: His immediate problem is that he doesn't seem to understand how expressions are evaluated in C++.  But in general, it would be poor design to have `+` and not `+=`.  And it's very trivial to implement `+` in terms of `+=`, without the need of friends.  (The trick of using a class template as a base to provide it is less well known, but makes things a lot easier if you are defining more than one class which supports overloading.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can approach this. The normal way with operators is, you just create a normal two operand operator, and then chain the calls together. For example `a + b + c + d` => `operator+(operator+(operator+(a + b), c), d)`.

Alternately, create your own named function or member that provides a multi-parameter version, using the name to accurately describe what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading http://www.cs.rit.edu/~mjh/docs/c++-faq/operator-overloading.html

To the best of my understanding you do not need 2 parameters here. Your overload needs to return an object which the result of your operation. In this case your example class+class+class can actually be written as class+(class+class) so that (class+class) is processed first and then the result of that is added to the third class.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to use arithmetic operators with two parameters. For example:

```
//References are used here as arguments.
Cents operator+(const Cents &c1, const Cents &c2)
{
    // use the Cents constructor and operator+(int, int)
    return Cents(c1.m_nCents + c2.m_nCents);
}
```

(Source: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/)

Note: you need to declare the operator "function" as *friend* in class definition if you need to use private members of your class in it.

If you then return a class type same with those given as arguments (objects or references of them as here), you can do class + class + class..., assuming that each operator+ call is between 2 arguments, and the result is added to the third one invoking again the operator+ "function" etc.